# Right cosets of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm self studying Artin and I think I understand how right and left cosets work, but I have a question that involves the right cosets of $S_3$, and I'm confused on how to do it. I have $H = \{1,y\}$ so do I just multiply $1,y,xy$ to the right of $H$? Like same process for left cosets but just multiplying the variables to the right of it instead of left?

But that would give me the same as the left cosets and I know that the left and right cosets of $S_3$ are not the same, but then I don't know how else to proceed.

Comment: The right cosets of $H$ are sets of the form $Hg$ with $g\in S_3$. So for each $g\in S_3$, the corresponding right coset is the set $\{1g,yg\} = \{g,yg\}$. For left cosets, you take a single $g\in S_3$, and look at $gH = \{g1,gy\} = \{g,gy\}$.  You will find that you do *not* always get the same left cosets and right cosets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin forgive me for being dense, but won't that give me 6 right cosets? Or do I just eliminate the ones that are same between the left and right cosets?

Comment: Each coset will occur twice, so you will end up with 3 *distinct* cosets. For example, $H1 = \{11,y1\} = \{1,y\} = \{1y,yy\} = Hy$.